# Can't the runtime size of instances of a class with virtual methods be optimized more by g++?

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, size, vtable

I just checked the size of a class containing dozens of virtual methods with g++ (4.7), because I had heard pointers are used for virtual methods and I thought that would be a terrible implementation, as it would take up 80 bytes for each instance of a class with a mere 10 virtual methods that way on my system.

To my relief, `sizeof(<insert typename here>)` returned only 8 bytes, the size of a pointer on my system. I assume this means that it stores a pointer to the vtable, rather than each method and that I simply misunderstood what people were saying (or perhaps that most compilers are stupid).

However, before I finally tested this, I had been struggling with using virtual methods as pointers the way I expected them to work. I noticed that the address was in fact a relatively very low number, often under 100 and with a difference of 8 bytes compared to other ones, so I assumed it was some sort of index for an array. And then I went pondering about how I would implement vtables myself, and that would not be using a pointer, as the results of my test clearly show. I was surprised to see it use a whole 8 bytes (I verified whether or not it was just padding by inserting a char field, which returned 16 bytes with sizeof).

Instead, I would implement this by storing an array index (for example 4 bytes, or even 2 if 65536 or less classes with virtual methods are used) which would be searched for in a look-up table containing pointers to the vtables, and find it that way. So why is a pointer stored? For performance reasons, or did they simply reuse the code for 32-bit operating systems (as it would make no difference in memory size there)?

Thank you in advance.

**edit:**

Someone requested me to calculate the actual memory saved, and I decided to make a code example. Unfortunately, it became quite big (they requested me to use 10 virtual methods in both), but I tested it and it actually works. Here it comes:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

/* For the singleton lovers in this community */
class VirtualTableManager
{
    unsigned capacity, count;
    void*** vtables;
public:
    ~VirtualTableManager() {
        delete vtables;
    }
    static VirtualTableManager& getInstance() {
        static VirtualTableManager instance;
        return instance;
    }
    unsigned addElement(void** vtable) {
        if (count == capacity)
        {
            vtables = (void***) realloc(vtables, (capacity += 0x2000) * sizeof(void**));  /* Reserves an extra 64KiB of pointers */
        }
        vtables[count] = vtable;
        return count++;
    }
    void** getElement(unsigned index) {
        return index < capacity ? vtables[index] : 0; /* Just in case: "Hey guys, let's misuse the API!" */
    }
private:
    VirtualTableManager() : capacity(0), count(0), vtables(0) { }
    VirtualTableManager(const VirtualTableManager&);
    void operator =(const VirtualTableManager&);
};

class Real
{
public:
    short someField; /* This is required to show the difference, because of padding */
    Real() : someField(0) { }
    virtual ~Real() {
        printf("Real::~Real()\n");
    }
    virtual void method0() {
        printf("Real::method0()\n");
    }
    virtual void method1(short argument) {
        someField = argument;
    }
    virtual short method2() {
        return someField;
    }
    virtual void method3() { }
    virtual void method4() { }
    virtual void method5() { }
    virtual void method6() { }
    virtual void method7() { }
    virtual void method8() { }
};

class Fake
{
    static void** vtable;
    static unsigned classVIndex; /* Don't know what to call it, please forgive me for the lame identifier */
public:
    unsigned instanceVIndex;
    short someField;
    Fake() : instanceVIndex(classVIndex), someField(0) { }
    ~Fake() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[9])(this);
    }
    void method0() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[0])(this);
    }
    void method1(short argument) {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*, short argument)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[1])(this, argument);
    }
    short method2() {
        return reinterpret_cast<short (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[2])(this);
    }
    void method3() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[3])(this);
    }
    void method4() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[4])(this);
    }
    void method5() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[5])(this);
    }
    void method6() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[6])(this);
    }
    void method7() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[7])(this);
    }
    void method8() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(Fake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[8])(this);
    }
protected:
    Fake(unsigned instanceVIndex, short someField)
        : instanceVIndex(instanceVIndex), someField(someField) { }
    /* The 'this' keyword is an automatically passed pointer, so I'll just manually pass it and identify it as 'self' (thank you, lua, I would have used something like 'vthis', which would be boring and probably incorrect) */
    static void vmethod0(Fake* self) {
        printf("Fake::vmethod0(%p)\n", self);
    }
    static void vmethod1(Fake* self, short argument) {
        self->someField = argument;
    }
    static short vmethod2(Fake* self) {
        return self->someField;
    }
    static void vmethod3(Fake* self) { }
    static void vmethod4(Fake* self) { }
    static void vmethod5(Fake* self) { }
    static void vmethod6(Fake* self) { }
    static void vmethod7(Fake* self) { }
    static void vmethod8(Fake* self) { }
    static void vdestructor(Fake* self) {
        printf("Fake::vdestructor(%p)\n", self);
    }
};

class DerivedFake : public Fake
{
    static void** vtable;
    static unsigned classVIndex;
public:
    DerivedFake() : Fake(classVIndex, 0) { }
    ~DerivedFake() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(DerivedFake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[1])(this);
    }
    void method0() {
        reinterpret_cast<void (*)(DerivedFake*)>(VirtualTableManager::getInstance().getElement(instanceVIndex)[0])(this);
    }
protected:
    DerivedFake(unsigned instanceVIndex, short someField)
        : Fake(instanceVIndex, someField) { }
    static void vmethod0(DerivedFake* self) {
        printf("DerivedFake::vmethod0(%p)\n", self);
    }
    static void vdestructor(DerivedFake* self) {
        printf("DerivedFake::vdestructor(%p)\n", self);
        Fake::vdestructor(self); /* call parent destructor */
    }
};

/* Make the vtable */
void** Fake::vtable = (void*[]) {
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod0, (void*) &Fake::vmethod1,
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod2, (void*) &Fake::vmethod3,
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod4, (void*) &Fake::vmethod5,
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod6, (void*) &Fake::vmethod7,
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod8, (void*) &Fake::vdestructor
};
/* Store the vtable and get the look-up index */
unsigned Fake::classVIndex = VirtualTableManager::getInstance().addElement(Fake::vtable);

/* Do the same for derived class */
void** DerivedFake::vtable = (void*[]) {
    (void*) &DerivedFake::vmethod0, (void*) &Fake::vmethod1,
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod2, (void*) &Fake::vmethod3,
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod4, (void*) &Fake::vmethod5,
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod6, (void*) &Fake::vmethod7,
    (void*) &Fake::vmethod8, (void*) &DerivedFake::vdestructor
};
unsigned DerivedFake::classVIndex = VirtualTableManager::getInstance().addElement(DerivedFake::vtable);

int main_virtual(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("size of 100 instances of Real including padding is %lu bytes\n"
           "size of 100 instances of Fake including padding is %lu bytes\n",
            sizeof(Real[100]), sizeof(Fake[100]));
    Real *real = new Real;
    Fake *fake = new Fake;
    Fake *derived = new DerivedFake;
    real->method1(123);
    fake->method1(456);
    derived->method1(789);
    printf("real::method2() = %hi\n"
           "fake::method2() = %hi\n"
           "derived::method2() = %hi\n", real->method2(), fake->method2(), derived->method2());
    real->method0();
    fake->method0();
    derived->method0();
    delete real;
    delete fake;
    delete derived;
    return 0;
}
```

Fear not, I do not normally put the definition in classes like that. I just did it here to *hopefully* improve readability. Anyway, the output:

```
size of 100 instances of Real including padding is 1600 bytes
size of 100 instances of Fake including padding is 800 bytes
real::method2() = 123
fake::method2() = 456
derived::method2() = 789
Real::method0()
Fake::vmethod0(0x1bd8040)
DerivedFake::vmethod0(0x1bd8060)
Real::~Real()
Fake::vdestructor(0x1bd8040)
DerivedFake::vdestructor(0x1bd8060)
Fake::vdestructor(0x1bd8060)
```

It might not be thread-safe, might contain a fearsome legion of bugs, and might also be relatively inefficient, but I hope it demonstrates my concept. It was tested on 64-bit Ubuntu with g++-4.7. I doubt there is any size benefit on 32-bit systems, and since I save less than a word (4 bytes, so much for that!) I had to put a field in there to make the effects show. Feel free to benchmark the speed though (please optimize it first if you do, I rushed this) or test the effects on other architectures/platforms and with other compilers (I'd like to see the results, so please share them if you do). Something similar may be useful when someone finds the need to make a 128/256-bit platform, creates a processor which has very limited memory support but incredible speed or with compilers that use like 21 bytes for the vtable on each instance.

**edit:**

Whoops, the code example was a *derp*. Fixed it.

Comment: This might create weird side-effects in the code that could be hard to deal with. For example, the offset of a data member in a class changing something else because a new virtual class was added. Also, space is traded for time, because a virtual method call now requires two derferences.

Comment: @user315052- Aren't two dereferences already required - one for the vtable pointer, and one for the function start address?

Comment: This would make one additional dereference.

Comment: @RPFeltz I see that you have accepted an answer already, but could you please add to your question kind of calculation how much memory you can save. For example you have an appplication with 100 classes that have 10 virtual methods each. In case vtables are used your applicaton will use 100 * 10 * sizeof(function pointer) bytes to store vtables. And how much memory can you save if your idea is used?

Comment: @skwllsp I was referring to the way to match classes to the right vtables, not to storing the actual function pointers (which I used to believe were stored in the actual instance). It currently seems to be a pointer to a table containing pointers to functions, and I was proposing a way to reduce the size further by using an index for a table containing pointers to tables containing pointers to functions. Would you like a code example of how this would save memory when creating instances though?

Comment: @RPFeltz Yes, I understand that you are suggesting - `an index for a table containing pointers to tables containing pointers to functions`. I am actually interested in understanding how much memory in a simple scanario (100 classes with 10 virtual functions each) your implemenation exactly will use.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use truncated pointers, and put all the vtables below the 4GB mark?

Comment: @harold Can you truncate pointers if the vtable size is variable? Or what did you mean by truncate anyway? And what about dynamic linking, is it worth reserving 4GB in each executable file for vtables? I doubt it.

Comment: Well you'd only need to make sure that the upper 32 bits of the point was always zero, and then you could just forget about those upper bits. That doesn't really imply reserving 4GB for the vtables, it just means that you put the vtables below 4GB, potentially along with whatever else you want to put there, or just a gap (unreserved pages) which doesn't cost anything.

Comment: @harold Oh, you meant an integer of 32 bits by a truncated pointer? That's an interesting idea. It's also presumable that you don't use more than 4GiB on loaded libraries combined (I only have 4GiB RAM anyway). But what would you do for libraries loaded during runtime, if that's really possible? Imagine you reserve some memory for the vtables, so that they can be loaded in there. Now suddenly, you load libbehemoth, the king of bloated libraries. You didn't reserve enough memory to load the vtables in. What do you do? 1: (Kernel) panic. 2: Shift all memory to make space. 3: You tell me.

Comment: Unless popular operating systems actually allow loading pointers relatively from the start of your program in memory. That would make it fairly straightforward. How does it handle such things anyway?

Comment: With what I had in mind, probably a nice crash.. I probably should have thought it through first :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One challenge with an array-based vtable is how you would link together several compiled source files.  If each compiled file stored its own table, the linker would have to combine those tables together when producing the final binary.  This increases the complexity of the linker, which now has to be made aware of this new C++-specific detail.

Additionally, the byte-saving techniques you described would be tricky to get right with multiple compilation units.  What if you have two source files, each of which has few enough classes to use two bytes per vtable index, but which combined now need three bytes?  In that case, the linker would have to rewrite the object files based on the new object size.

Additionally, this new system would not interact well with dynamic linking.  If you had a separate object file that was linked in at runtime, you would have two or more global tables of vtables.  The generated object code would then have to take this into account, which would increase code generator complexity.

Finally, there's alignment issues.  Using two or four bytes for the index when the word size is eight bytes might degrade program performance if it offset all the other fields of the object.  In fact, its entirely possible that g++ only uses four bytes, but then pads to eight.

In short, there is no reason why you couldn't do this optimization, but it comes at a significant implementation complexity and (possibly) at a runtike cost.  That said, it's a very clever idea!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this great and most satisfactory answer! I was already doubting variable index sizes, but 4 bytes would be plenty for it to work and still be a small bonus. However, the dynamic linking issue is certainly a valid point which I did not think of, and I believe it makes this whole method pointless as it would require extra information (unless you concatenate the tables somewhere and sacrifice more performance speed by making the array position a pointer). I also considered the possibility of a performance bonus of using the word size, and this verifies it.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a trade-off. To be an improvement, any scheme to save space would have to at least *often* save space and *never* lose speed.

If you put a 2 or 4 byte index in the class, and I then add a pointer as the first member, there will have to be some padding to get the right alignment for my pointer.

So now the class is 16 bytes anyway. If the indexing is then just even *slightly* slower than using a vtable pointer, it is a net loss.

I can accept that it is not always a reduction in size, but I don't want to lose some speed for *no* gain in size.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it's simpler for the CPU to pre-fetch a simple address rather than an index to an array (plus, of course, the extra de-references). You would add more than the cost of a single de-reference.